# Proving a subsequence limit Given $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}=\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1$ , $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1=1)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Prove that there is a subsequence of $(a_n)=\{\sqrt n\}$ with a limit equal to one $(L=1)$ given  $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}=\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1$ , $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}$ is the fractional part of a floor function ,and also given  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1=1)$

First we need to show that there is a an increasing subsequence of natural numbers so the hint is in $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\} $ so I think that the subsequence will be $(a_{k^2-1})$ $k \in \Bbb N$ then also $k^2-1 \in \Bbb N$ and $k+1 > k$ $\Rightarrow$ $(k+1)^2 >k^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $(k+1)^2-1 >k^2-1$ therefore it is an increasing subsequence.

According to $(a_n)=\{\sqrt n\}$ we get $(a_{k^2-1})=\{\sqrt {k^2-1}\}$ and according to $ \{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}=\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1$ we get $ \{\sqrt{k^2-1}\}=\sqrt{k^2-1}-k+1$ and also by the given information about the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(\sqrt{n^2-1}-n+1=1)$  we get $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty }\sqrt{k^2-1}-k+1=1$

is this right? am I missing something? some are suggesting that $k \geq 2$ but I dont see a reason for this.

thank you for any help and tips